# App for downloading and displaying a pdf within app just returns blank content

Tags: java, android

I searched the web for examples displaying pdf documents within a app. Additionally i searched for a Downloader class because i want to load the pdf from the internet. After execution it just displays blank PDF page.

MainActivity.java just sends the pdf link to the DisplayPDF.java Activity:

```
package com.example.pdfviewevaluation;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.pdfviewevaluation.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayPDF.class);
        String url = "pdf link";
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, url);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

DisplayPDF.java creates the Folder and PDF in the cache directory. Then it starts the Downloader with the pdf link and directory. Finally it should just show the pdf:

```
package com.example.pdfviewevaluation;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

    public class DisplayPDF extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_pdf);

        String pdfURL = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        File folder = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "pdf");
        folder.mkdir();
        File file = new File(folder, "Read.pdf");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Downloader dl = new Downloader(pdfURL, file);
        try {
            dl.execute().get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        showPdf();
    }

    public void showPdf() {
        File file = new File(this.getCacheDir()+"/pdf/Read.pdf");
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
        List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this.getApplicationContext(), this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Downloader.java connects to the pdf page and download the pdf from the given link to the desired directory:

```
package com.example.pdfviewevaluation;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Downloader extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    private String fileURL;
    private File directory;

    public Downloader(String fileURL, File directory)
    {
        this.fileURL = fileURL;
        this.directory = directory;
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(directory);
            URL u = new URL(fileURL);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            int i = 0;
            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            f.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely, you are crashing with a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Examine LogCat to look at what exceptions you are logging.

Comment: Split the solution into 2 parts to understand where the problem actually is: 1) store the downloaded file in a public directory and open it with a standard pdf reader to see if the file is corrupted 2) Try to open an existing pdf file from your filesystem to be sure you can display a pdf file you know is valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours spending on my problem i searched for another solution on YouTube. These one are showing the solution:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGlqHeB5hdk
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YPJCOxiklQ

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.downloadingfiles">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String myUrl = "http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf";
    private ImageView imageView;
    private int currentPage = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(myUrl));
        request.setTitle("File download.");
        request.setDescription("File is being downloaded...");
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        String nameOfFile = URLUtil.guessFileName(myUrl, null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(myUrl));
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, nameOfFile);
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);
    }


    BroadcastReceiver onComplete=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            render();
    }
};

    /**Called when the user clicks the "Next" button defined in activity_main.xml */
    public void nextPage(View view) {
        currentPage++;
        render();
    }

    /**Called when the user clicks the "Previous" button defined in activity_main.xml */
    public void previousPage(View view) {
        currentPage--;
        render();
    }

    private void render(){
        try{
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            int REQ_WIDTH = imageView.getWidth();
            int REQ_HEIGHT = imageView.getHeight();

            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(REQ_WIDTH, REQ_HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
            String nameOfFile = URLUtil.guessFileName(myUrl, null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(myUrl));
            File file = new File("/sdcard/Download/"+nameOfFile);
            PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));
            if(currentPage < 0){
                currentPage = 0;
            }else if(currentPage >= renderer.getPageCount()){
                currentPage = renderer.getPageCount() - 1;
            }

            Matrix m = imageView.getImageMatrix();
            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, REQ_WIDTH, REQ_HEIGHT);
            renderer.openPage(currentPage).render(bitmap, rect, m, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
            imageView.setImageMatrix(m);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            imageView.invalidate();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```